# Graphics.Blit how uv information is passed?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, rendering, render-to-texture, blit

does graphics.blit takes uv data from mesh having the material that is passed to Graphics.Blit call?

Comment: Blit does not deal with meshes at all. It's a texture -> texture operation.

Answer (score 1):

Blit operates on a virtual quad, having a full (0-1) sweep on both axis.